# ¿Como hacer que icono este siempre sobre input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, icons

tengo una pequeña duda, resulta que estoy realizando un sistema, y dentro del mismo hay un input de búsqueda junto con un  con el icono de una lupa, lo que quisiera es que el icono este siempre sobre el input aunque este tenga que moverse porque aparezcan mas opciones arriba (las opciones se generan con un for asi que pueden haber mas o menos).

html

```
 <input type="search" id="buscar" name="buscar"  />
 <i class="fa fa-search busca" id="lupa"></i>
```

js

```
var busqueda = document.getElementById("buscar");
var lupa = document.getElementById("lupa");
lupa.style.left = (parseInt(busqueda.offsetLeft)+39.5)+"%";
lupa.style.top = (parseInt(busqueda.offsetTop)+9)+"%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer esto:

```
i {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Y asumiendo que tu input y tu icono están dentro de un contenedor, a ese contenedor le tienes que añadir en el css el parámetro de `position: relative`.

De esta manera, solo con css, tendrías el icono encima del input siempre.

Comment: gracias, quien diria que era tan sencillo y yo pensando en soluciones complejas

Comment: No hay de que! Suerte en tu sistema.